# Bash Syntax error while using 'source' command in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bash

The error message displayed in my terminal has been pasted below.

```
sarvotham@ramanPC:~$ source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"'
```

The same command was used many times before with the same syntax  and it was working perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R is an R file. The command you're using is a R command syntax... But you're currently in a Bash shell.

Run `R` for an R shell, then try it again.

---

From the [install page](http://www.bioconductor.org/install/):

> Install the latest release of R, then get the latest version of Bioconductor **by starting R** and entering the commands
>
> ```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
> biocLite()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Probably that you had a function declared with this name (`source`), which is also part of bash in-built commands. The bash's `source` command will execute just local files.

To make it work again, declare again your own `source` function.

Comment: Thank you Frantique.Your reply was spot on . The source command i had to use was meant to be used in the R shell.